# C# запуск консольного приложения на ubuntu

Tags: c#, .net, ubuntu

Подскажите, как работает запуск простого консольного приложения  написанного на C# на debian. Я читал что там надо установить dotnet core. И стартовать приложение командой dotnet run. Скажите можно ли компилировать такое приложение специально под debian в один файл как например gcc компилирует код на с++ в исполняемый файл под любую ОС.
Интересует что это за дотнет, сильно ли это нагружает систему? какое то окружение поднимается по типу java машины?

возможно есть способ компилировать приложение c# в исполняемый файл под debian?

Comment: Да, это похоже на джаву, но есть отличия. Либо устанавливать dotnet core на целевую машину или не делать это, а скомпилировать программу таким образом, что в релизном пакете будут содержаться только те библиотеки из состава dotnet core, которые необходимы для работы вашей программы.

Comment: `...gcc компилирует код на с++ в исполняемый файл под любую ОС. ` - ну, да программу типа `Hello World`, наверное можно скомпилировать под все ОС сразу, а вот что-нибудь посложнее уже вряд ли. `...что это за дотнет, сильно ли это нагружает систему?` - дотнет работает и на IoT устройствах в том числе.

Comment: Под Debian не пробовал, но под Ubuntu нормально работает компилируемый код в исполняемый файл, как с зависимостью под установленный Net.Core, так и независимый. В принципе на любом линуксе должно запускаться.

Comment: а сильно распухает файл если все зависимости он включает в себя? и могу я это все откомпилировать под виндой? или надо ставить dotnet на линукс целевую машину

Comment: @АлексЛизенберг "Hello World!" независимый занимает порядка 75 Мб, не думаю что это много для единичного проекта. Компилируется все под виндой в Visual Studio. Можно компилировать как в один файл,  так и в кучу файлов, разница только во времени первого запуска.

Answer (score 2):

`dotnet publish --output bin/Release/linux-x64 --configuration Release --runtime linux-x64 --self-contained /p:PublishSingleFile=true /p:PublishTrimmed=true`

выполни эту команду на машине разработчика и получи в директории `bin/Release/linux-x64` один большой файл, который в теории должен работать на любом linux свежее ubuntu 16.04. И да, ничего устанавливать на клиентской тачке не потребуется.

Comment: прям под виндой можно выполнить?

Comment: @АлексЛизенберг да. 

Также все эти параметры можно прописать в файле csproj